# gwan v7.12.6 cannot show index.html

Tags: g-wan

Visit 127.0.0.1/index.html responses 404 not found.
It is not because of file permission, since I followed the steps in gwan official site to set up the file permissions.

In the error.log, it show:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] 404 "GET /index.html/"
[client 127.0.0.1] 404 "GET /imgs/errors.css/"
```

See, the trailing "/" at the end of the lines.
Should it be /index.html, without the ending "/"?

How can I work around it?

--- Edit ---
Today, accidentally, I change the 0.0.0.0:80 to :81.
Strange! The index.html showed up.
But, other .html file still cannot be accessed.
G-WAN was lauched by sudo ./gwan.

When I changed back to :80 and launch with sudo ./gwan -d:kk:kk
Everything is OK, but cannot access the site with simply 127.0.0.1 or localhost.
It must be accessed by 127.0.0.1/index.html or localhost/index.html

All files and directories are with following permission settings:
rwxrwsr-x kk www-data

Answer (score 1):

I just run this same release stored under `/home/user/gwan` without any problem with the `./gwan` command.

If you are running `sudo ./gwan` instead then you will get `"error 404" (Not Found) HTTP errors` because then the files are not reachable for `'root'` (file system permission issue).

With `sudo ./gwan` you should copy gwan under something like `/opt/gwan` instead of a subfolder of `/home`.